# Register "from_avro" function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I have a dataframe that contains avro bytes and the schema string. I would like to convert the avro bytes using the schema.

Here is my sample code to convert the avro using spark sql:

```
val rsDf = ss.sql("SELECT from_avro(avro_payload, avro_schema_string) FROM testDF")
```

but I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'from_avro'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$LookupFunctions$$anonfun$apply$16.$anonfun$applyOrElse$121(Analyzer.scala:2084)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:53)
```

Any suggestion on how to call `from_avro` using spark-sql ?

Comment: It's not in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html, I don't know where did you see that spark-sql is supposed to support that

Comment: @yishaiz Is not a spark-sql function !